# Pandas Series skipna not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas

So it seems to me that the standard aggregation functions in pandas don't behave very consistently across the three main pandas datatypes (groupBy, DataFrame, Series) when trying to include NaNs.
There is already an issue open for the case of groupBy objects [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/43671), but it seems like something similar is happening when using pandas Series. Minimum example

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({"user": ["a", "a", "b"], "value": [3, None, 5], "other_value": [None, 4, 6]})
foo
>>>  
  user  value  other_value
0    a    3.0          NaN
1    a    NaN          3.0
2    b    5.0          6.0
```

Now when I try to get the maximum per row including NaNs using `max(skipna=False)` I get the expected:

```
foo[['value', 'other_value']].max(skipna=False, axis=1)
>>>>
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    6.0
```

However, when using the Series `max` operation, it seems to behave in a non-consistent way, depending on whether `NaN` was the first value in the Series:

```
foo.apply(lambda x: x[['value', 'other_value']].max(skipna=False), 1)
>>>
0    NaN
1    3.0
2    6.0
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?